# Notebook instance running R with a GPU

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I am new to cloud computing and GCP. I am trying to create a notebook instance running R with a GPU. I got a basic instance with 1 core and 0 GPUs to start and I was able to execute some code which was cool. When I try to create an instance with a GPU I keep getting all sorts of errors about something called live migration, or that there are no resources available, etc. Can someone tell me how to start an R notebook instance with a GPU? It can't be this difficult.

Comment: Can you share which product you are using and the steps you took to create your notebook?

Comment: I went to AI Platform (Unified) on the left and clicked create instance at the top.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to cloud computing and do not know exactly what you mean by product.

Comment: With product I mean exactly the tool you are using (in this case, AI Platform). Unfortunately AI Platform doesnt support using R language with GPUs

Answer (score 0):

The [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) (The Comprehensive R Archive Network) doesn't support GPU. However, you can follow this [link](https://www.zainrizvi.io/blog/using-gpus-with-r-in-jupyter-lab/) might help you to install a Notebook instance running R with a GPU. You need a machine with Nvidia GPU drivers installed then install R and Jupyter Lab. After that compile those R packages which require it for use with GPU's.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Are you familiar with creating instances in GCP? Does this mean if I want to use a GPU in R on GCP I have to create the instance with a custom container and then go through the steps in that link to manually install R?